# What is Rule to use ScrollBar in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, scrollbar

I'm learning about javafx `ScrollBar`. I know little about `ScrollPane` but I want to get grip on all controls. Here I tried to use javafx `ScrollBar`. but it is not working.

**Main Class:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ScrollBarExample extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("scroll.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

**Controller Class:**

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;

public class ScrollController{
    @FXML private Label label;
    @FXML private ScrollBar scroll;

    public void initialize(){
        scroll.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>(){
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> value, Number oldValue, Number newValue){
                label.setLayoutX(newValue.doubleValue());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**FXML Code:**

```xml
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane ?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label ?>

<GridPane prefWidth="300" prefHeight="250" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="ScrollController" >
    <children>
        <ScrollBar fx:id="scroll" min="0" max="100" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" />
        <Label fx:id="label" text="Move Me" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.columnIndex="0" />
    </children>
</GridPane>
```

So what are the rules to use `ScrollBar`? On which elements it could use or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the parent, i.e. the `GridPane`. A `GridPane` sets the `layoutX` property itself. If this is changed, during the next layout pulse `GridPane` simply moves the `Node` "back where it belongs".

To make this work you could use the `translateX` property instead. The `translateX` property denotes the horizontal distance the node should be moved from it's layout position. With this approach it would also be easier to bind the properties instead of using a listener:

```
label.translateXProperty().bind(scroll.valueProperty());
```

---

Alternatively you could use a parent that does not set the layout position itself (like `Pane`) or set the `managed` property to `false` to prevent the parent from modifying the child's position and size. Note that in this case you need to set the `layoutY` yourself, since this property isn't set by the `Parent` either.

Comment: fabian can you explain the difference between layoutX and translateX? I searched but didn't found the easy answer for me.

Comment: @Nothing: `layoutX` is where the node is placed, before any transformations are applied; "transformation properties", like `translateX` can modify where/how the node is actually drawn. If `translateX` is the only "transformation property" set, the position the label has for layouting starts at `x = layoutX`, but the position where it's actually drawn is `x = layoutX + translateX`; see also [`Node.boundsInParent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#boundsInParentProperty)

Comment: Can you take a look here? I Draw an image to understand. http://imgur.com/a/vRlOj I'm right? or can you draw such image please?

Comment: @Nothing: translateX/Y should not be the distance from the top left of the original position to the bottomright of the new position but the distance from the topleft of the original position to the topleft of the new position. It works similar to the `translate` property of css: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

Comment: Nice man!. Graphic always helpful. Ok last question. then what is `setX` and `getX` if there is already `setLayoutX` and `getLayoutX`?

Comment: @Nothing: In this case this property is a bit confusing, since also moves the `Shape`'s layout position (before transforms). However this property also does not influence the position in case the parent sets the layout position.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand about which property you are talking? can you give me any example code?